# Date time query SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Date Column Order_Date In date Time format Isdat
14/05/2018 13:13:06 This is format) , I need To Extract Today's Order before 14:00 P:M 'O' Clock and in Second Column I want to extract order after 15:00 P:M i.e  Time from 15:00 P:M till 23:00 P:M in SQL SERVER,

Date Is in 24:00 Hor Format.

In output Order_date Should be 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss '  Format

Comment: What data type is your column?

Comment: You can filter your rows by a particular range, but if you want data in columns (as you say "second column") you will have to pivot. Please include some sample data and expected output so it's clearer.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I can't tell if you want to filter rows or add a new column or what you want to do.  I'm not sure was "extract today's order" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Date types have no format. They are binary values. Formats apply *only* when parsing text or formatting a date value as text. What are you *actually* trying to do? Are you trying to pass a date parameter to a query? Or display results to the end user? In both cases you *shouldn't* use strings

Comment: Post the query you used and the actual table definition. What is `Order_Date`? A string field (bad idea)? A `datetime`? Or do you have separate date and time fields? You don't need string conversions, you need to use the appropriate date functions to filter the results. You could eg just use `cast(order_date as time) between ...` although that wouldn't use any indexes

Comment: Ordernumber Today'sDatetimeFrom 09:00A:MTill14:00P:M Today'sDatetimeFrom 09:00A:MTill14:00P:M
1 2018-05-14 10:26:15 2018-05-14  15:26:15 AM
2 2018-05-14 11:26:15 2018-05-14   17:26:15 AM
3 2018-05-14 00:26:15 2018-05-14 19:26:15 AM

Comment: I am sure there are simple solutions for your problem, but until you provide more information nobody can answer this. Edit your question and tell us what datatype `Order_Date`is and show us your query

Comment: @Bilal update the question. Post the query and the table definition. Posting a bunch of dates doesn't help. Dates have no format, you can display them any way you want.

Comment: Already written that Order_date is a column in date time format where the salesman who made the order at a particular time used to store in that column in 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' format

Comment: date time has no format, so we still dont know what datatype this column is.

Comment: cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)+(14/cast(24 as float)) this is giving an error,,Coversion Error,My Order_date is in Varchar Data type

Comment: And why are you storing a date as a `varchar`? First step here should be fixing that problem.

Comment: Table has lot of values..my date is varchar now how can i get order before 14:00 P:M and order between 15:00 P:M and 23:00

Comment: Why is your date/time stored as varchar? You should fix that first.

Comment: Now all the column is in 14/05/2018 10:26:15 this format in table ,It will not convert in Datetime format,giving an Error

Comment: If you keep your date+time in a varchar format you are asking for trouble. Don't expect us to deal with your trouble. Convert it to a bona fide date+time and ask again.

Comment: I want it to change it to Date time Data type, but i am unable to change it out of range error coming.

But Now i have already stored it as varchar and it has 2 Millions record in this format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Now it is not converting into datetime format,,how should i convert it...

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, the first thing you need to do is fix your data; storing a date as a `varchar` is a bad design choice. Always use a data type that is representative of you data; stores dates as a `date`, numbers as an `int`/`decimal`, etc.

According to the [documentation] there is no style code for `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, however, a quick SQL as below told me that style code 103 does work:

```
DECLARE @date varchar(50) = '31/05/2017 19:12:56';

WITH N AS (
    SELECT 1 AS i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1
    FROM N
    WHERE I + 1 <= 150)
SELECT I, TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),@Date,I) AS Conversion
FROM N
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 150);
```

So, firstly, let's fix that data of yours. So, let's add the new column in and drop your old one.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD OrderDate datetime2(0);

UPDATE YourTable
SET OrderDate = CONVERT(datetime2(0),YourDateColumn,103);
GO

ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP COLUMN YourDateColumn;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.YourTable.OrderDate','YourDateColumn','COLUMN';
```

Ok, now we've got rid of your awful datatype, and got your new column. Good.

Now, you want to specifically query time here; if you're doing that, ideally you want to separate the value of the time and date out. Using something like `WHERE CONVERT(time, YourDateColumn) BETWEEN '14:00' AND '15:00'` makes the query non-SARGHable. Thus let's use a couple of computed columns for that:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD OrderDate AS CONVERT(date, YourDateColumn);
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD OrderTime AS CONVERT(time, YourDateColumn);
```

Now, to your question at hand: *"I need To Extract Today's Order before 14:00 P:M 'O' Clock and in Second Column I want to extract order after 15:00 P:M i.e Time from 15:00 P:M till 23:00 P:M in SQL SERVER"*. honestly, this is non-sensical; putting different orders based on time in different columns? I have no idea what you mean here, I'm afraid, and I have no sample data or expected results to work with. Thus, instead, i'll show you how to return orders after `14:00` but before '15:00` on a specific date:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE OrderDate = '20170515'
  AND OrderTime >= '14:00'
  AND OrderTime < '15:00';
```

If you need more detail than that, you have a lot of comments asking you for more detail; I suggest you have a look at those. :)

Comment: Thank You so Much for your answer

Comment: Datetime 2 and Tryconvert is to not a recognized built-in function name sql server 2014.

Comment: @Bilal `datetime 2` and `tryconvert` aren't no, as neither are spelt correctly. It's `datetime2` and `TRY_CONVERT`. `datetime2` was introduced in SQL Server 2008, and `TRY_CONVERT` in 2012. They are both in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @Bilal for your reference: [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) & [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Please do some due-diligence before stating something doesn't exist in a version of SQL Server. :)